# Loading Model from another model file in extjs

Tags: extjs

```
formGrid=me.abstractComponent.query('grid[itemId=grid]')[0],
Objmodel= Ext.create('Ext.document.model.GridModel');
formStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
model:Objmodel,
data: data
}); 
formGrid.bindStore(formStore);
formStore.load();
```

I've been trying to load the store using the model, but error occurs saying that model not found. Is there any way such that i can load the model from another file in store above?

Answer (score 0):

Store model attribute means you have to give the definition of Model not instance of model

```
Ext.define('app.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['first', 'last']
});
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
      model: 'app.model.User'
    });
```

Now if you want to add data to grid using model

```
 var model = Ext.ModelManager.create({
    first: 'Ed',
    last: 'Spencer'
}, 'app.model.User');
    store.add(model)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time..but i wanted to get the model from another file but it did not work. There is no problem with the data load but there was a problem while loading the model to the store. I used the field attribute inside the store to get the data displayed in the grid but I am not quite happy as the model's field code is getting redundant. And now, it works just fine..